# ScholarOne and LaTeX

Tags: conversion

I have to convert a Latex-file using ScholarOne.
Unfortunately, it doesn't convert to pdf.
When I use Texmaker everything is fine.

Thanks for your help in advance.

This is part of the .log-file.

````
Conversion Pass Number 1

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2023.8.16)  26 OCT 2023 09:22
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Text.tex
(./Text.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/ScholarOne/latex/stack4/latex-styles/IOP/iopart.cls
Document Class: iopart 1996/06/10 v0.0 IOP Journals LaTeX article class
(/ScholarOne/latex/stack4/latex-styles/IOP/iopart12.clo
File: iopart12.clo 1997/01/15 v1.0 LaTeX2e file (size option)
)
\c@jnl=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\indentedwidth=\skip43
\mathindent=\dimen102
\c@eqnval=\count87
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2012/05/21 v3.02 (NLCT)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))) (/usr/share/te
xlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2012/05/21 v1.06 (NLCT)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count89
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count90
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks16
\@glsmrest=\toks17
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen103
)
\gls@level=\count91
\@gls@tmpb=\toks19
\gls@tmplen=\skip44
\glswrite=\write3
\glskeylisttok=\toks20
\glslabeltok=\toks21
\glsshorttok=\toks22
\glslongtok=\toks23

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.st
y
Package: glossary-hypernav 2007/07/04 v1.01 (NLCT)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2011/03/28 v3.0 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip45
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2011/03/28 v3.0 (NLCT)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip46
\LTright=\skip47
\LTpre=\skip48
\LTpost=\skip49
\LTchunksize=\count92
\LTcapwidth=\dimen104
\LT@head=\box26
\LT@firsthead=\box27
\LT@foot=\box28
\LT@lastfoot=\box29
\LT@cols=\count93
\LT@rows=\count94
\c@LT@tables=\count95
\c@LT@chunks=\count96
\LT@p@ftn=\toks24
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip50
\glspagelistwidth=\skip51
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2011/03/28 v3.0 (NLCT)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count97
\ST@wd=\dimen105
\ST@rightskip=\skip52
\ST@leftskip=\skip53
\ST@parfillskip=\skip54
\ST@pageleft=\dimen106
\ST@headht=\dimen107
\ST@tailht=\dimen108
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen109
\ST@pboxht=\dimen110
\ST@lineht=\dimen111
\ST@stretchht=\dimen112
\ST@prevht=\dimen113
\ST@toadd=\dimen114
\ST@dimen=\dimen115
\ST@pbox=\box30
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2011/03/28 v3.0 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip55
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty (/usr/share/tex
live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex
/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l
3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
)
Package: expl3 2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty
Package: l3seq 2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty
Package: l3int 2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count98
\l_tmpa_int=\count99
\l_tmpb_int=\count100
\g_tmpa_int=\count101
\g_tmpb_int=\count102
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty
Package: l3quark 2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty
Package: l3prg 2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count103
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty
Package: l3clist 2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty
Package: l3token 2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty
Package: l3prop 2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty
Package: l3msg 2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty
Package: l3file 2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count104
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count105
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count106
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count107
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count108
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty
Package: l3skip 2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen116
\c_max_dim=\dimen117
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen118
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen119
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen120
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen121
\c_zero_skip=\skip56
\c_max_skip=\skip57
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip58
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip59
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip60
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip61
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty
Package: l3keys 2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count109
\l_keys_choice_int=\count110
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty
Package: l3fp 2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count113
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count114
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count115
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count116
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count117
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count118
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count119
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty
Package: l3box 2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box31
\l_tmpa_box=\box32
\l_tmpb_box=\box33
\g_tmpa_box=\box34
\g_tmpb_box=\box35
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty
Package: l3coffins 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box36
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen128
\c_empty_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box39
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box40
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen131
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty
Package: l3color 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty
Package: l3luatex 2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count120
\g__cctab_stack_int=\count121
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty
Package: l3candidates 2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen132
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen133
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen134
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen135
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen136
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen137
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen138
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen139
\l__box_internal_box=\box45
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen140
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen141
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen142
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen143
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen144
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen145
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen146
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
))
Package: siunitx 2012/06/13 v2.5e A comprehensive (SI) units package
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen147
\extrarowheight=\dimen148
\NC@list=\toks25
\extratabsurround=\skip62
\backup@length=\skip63

LaTeX Warning: Command \@xhline  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2013/03/12 v4467 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l_siunitx_tmp_box=\box46
\l_siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen149
\l_siunitx_tmp_int=\count122
Variant \prop_get:NVNT already defined; not changing it on line 360
Variant \prop_get:NVNF already defined; not changing it on line 361
Variant \prop_get:NVNTF already defined; not changing it on line 362
\l_siunitx_number_mantissa_length_int=\count123
\l_siunitx_number_uncert_length_int=\count124
\l_siunitx_round_int=\count125
\l_siunitx_process_decimal_int=\count126
\l_siunitx_process_uncertainty_int=\count127
\l_siunitx_process_fixed_int=\count128
\l_siunitx_process_integer_min_int=\count129
\l_siunitx_process_precision_int=\count130
\l_siunitx_group_min_int=\count131
\l_siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box47
\l_siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box48
\l_siunitx_angle_marker_dim=\dimen150
\l_siunitx_angle_unit_dim=\dimen151
\l_siunitx_unit_int=\count132
\l_siunitx_unit_denominator_int=\count133
\l_siunitx_unit_numerator_int=\count134
\l_siunitx_unit_prefix_int=\count135
\l_siunitx_unit_prefix_base_int=\count136
\l_siunitx_unit_prefix_gram_int=\count137
\l_siunitx_number_product_int=\count138
\c_siunitx_one_fill_skip=\skip64

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5687 ...e_fill_skip { \c_zero_skip plus 1 fill }
                                                  
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\l_siunitx_table_unit_align_skip=\skip65
\l_siunitx_table_exponent_dim=\dimen152
\l_siunitx_table_integer_dim=\dimen153
\l_siunitx_table_mantissa_dim=\dimen154
\l_siunitx_table_marker_dim=\dimen155
\l_siunitx_table_result_dim=\dimen156
\l_siunitx_table_uncert_dim=\dimen157
\l_siunitx_table_fill_pre_dim=\dimen158
\l_siunitx_table_fill_post_dim=\dimen159
\l_siunitx_table_fill_mid_dim=\dimen160
\l_siunitx_table_pre_box=\box49
\l_siunitx_table_post_box=\box50
\l_siunitx_table_mantissa_box=\box51
\l_siunitx_table_result_box=\box52
\l_siunitx_table_number_align_skip=\skip66
\l_siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip67
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7060 \NewDocumentCommand
                           \DeclareBinaryPrefix { m m m } {
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.7060 \NewDocumentCommand \DeclareBinaryPrefix
                                                { m m m } {
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \siunitx_#_function:w.
<to be read again> ```
````

Comment: You are using a 2013 latex !!! and `\NewDocumentCommand` was added to latex last year. that will not work. it might possibly work if you add `\usepackage{xparse}` for a legacy package version of `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: Showing a log and no code, rarely helps much. The first line however, seems to indicate you are on `TeX Live 2013`! You should probably update

Comment: @daleif I think "ScholarOne" is an online submission system so the document author can't update (but had better not use commands that were only added last year)

Comment: I checked the change log: it was added in 2020 not last year, but certainly not available in 2013 (without using `xparse`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I have to use ScholarOne for the submission.

Comment: TL/`siunitx` versions seem to match those reported in https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/228

Comment: Thanks! The upload of an actual version of siunitx solved the problem.

Comment: can you post that as an answer (and accept) rather than add solutions to the question, that messes up the question-and-answer format of the site. didn't you need to add xparse as well?

Comment: No, I didn't have to add xparse

Answer (score 1):

The relevant error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7060 \NewDocumentCommand
```

the problem is that you are using a texlive 2013  (!!!) system so all files are 10 years old, `\NewDocumentCommand` was added to LaTeX in 2020 so not in the version you have.

You could try adding

`\usepackage{xparse}`

which is the original package based version of this command. That will fix the error shown but other features may also fail in a tex system that is that old. (you seem to have errors from `siunitx`, possibly because you are using version 3 features but only version 2 is available, hard to tell with no code shown)

You could try reporting this to ScholarOne and see if they can update their TeX system.

If you want to test your document before submission, you could try running it at Overleaf, which does not have a system quite that old but will let you test in texlive 2014.

Comment: I know nothing of SchalarOne, but the OP's expereicne is surely not unique. The sceicne library at the nearby major university has workstations with up-to-date OS, and some software that is old enough that it immediately crashes when launched (too old for the upgraded OS). Has not been fixed for at least 2 years. This place turns out software engineers! But they are not in charge of the library software. Or maybe they are?

Comment: Isn't `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` from `l.5687 ...e_fill_skip { \c_zero_skip plus 1 fill }` the first error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I read `expl3` and understood `xparse`. Same esoteric stuff to me `:-)`

Comment: @DaiBowen oh siunitx v2 or v3 yes we could just blame Joseph but I did say "other features may also fail in a tex system that is that old"  (I'll add a note about siunitx)

Answer (score 1):

The upload of an actual version of siunitx solved the problem.